# How does the focal length of the lens change the distance from the camera to an object?

Tags: optics, vision, imaging

I am reviewing some old image processing notes and have the following problem:

> I have a camera with a projection plane of $2cm\ by\ 2cm$ and a $15mm$
>   lens.  If you want an $1.5m$ object to take up half of the resulting
>   image, how far away should it be?

It seems like the standard $x = \frac{fX}{Z}$ equation should be useful here, but I am not sure if this information gives focal length at all.  How should this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"15mm lens" the 15mm would be the focal length

ps. make sure you use consistent units

Comment: Is that always the case?  The size of the lens is the focal length?

Comment: @Porridge in astronomy you would be more interested in the diameter but otherwise if you are only given one number it's the focal length